# Behavior of static property in PHP

Tags: php, static-members

I'm trying to understand how static property works.My example:

```
class Model_Cart{
    static public $_a;
}
```

I created object of this class in different scripts. Script 1:

```
 Model_Cart::$_a = true;
 var_dump(Model_Cart::$_a);
```

Output is "true".

But if I execute second script after:

```
var_dump(Model_Cart::$_a)
```

Output is NULL.

I expected that static variable is shared beetwen all instance of class. Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: What script are you executing before the `var_dump` ?

Comment: Are you running the 2nd script in a different request? because variables are not shared between requests :)

Comment: FYI, you don't5 have any objects or class instances.

Comment: @Shamil I didn't execute anything before var_dump.It's just test scripts

Comment: @onetrickpony Yes, I run 2nd script in different request

Comment: @Tamara that's your answer, you can't share variables across requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share variables across requests - they would need to be either send via a `POST` or `GET` request.

Comment: Whilst `S_SESSION` could be used, using `$_SESSION` to store some things isn't ideal. Although the class is title `Cart`, I can't say it's appropriate to use `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is as expected actually. Please take note that you cannot - without the use of sessions, cookies or a database of some sort - share properties or values between requests. That's because http is a so called 'stateless protocol', which pretty much means that with every request the application is build up again from the ground up.

Please take a note at the following examples:

**script_number_one.php**

```
$my_var = 'hello world!';
echo $my_var; // does what you think it does
```

**script_number_two.php**

```
echo $my_var; // echoes nothing, or raises a warning that the var doesn't exist
```

As you can see it doesn't matter what you do in script one, as script two just doesn't know about no 1 (and doesn't care either actually).

Pretty much the same happens with your class. But you can do something else though, and this is probably what you did expect:

```
class myStaticClass {
    public static $static_var = 'Hello world!';

    public function alter_static_value($new_value) {
        self::$static_var = $new_value;
    }

}

$_obj_1 = new myStaticClass;
$_obj_2 = new myStaticClass;

echo $_obj_1::$static_var; // echoes 'Hello World!'
echo $_obj_2::$static_var; // also echoes 'Hello world!'

$_obj_1->alter_static_value('Bye world!');
echo $_obj_2::$static_var; // echoes 'Bye world!';
```

As you can see, a static value isn't particular for an object instance, but is specific for the whole class, and thus accessible for all objects that instantiated that particular class.

Hope this helps.